# What type should I use for a list of file or directory paths in CMake?

Tags: list, cmake, filenames, variable-types

Cached variables in CMake have one of several [types](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html):

| Type identifier | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `BOOL` | Boolean `ON`/`OFF` value. |
| `FILEPATH` | Path to a file on disk. |
| `PATH` | Path to a directory on disk. |
| `STRING` | A line of text. |
| `INTERNAL` | A line of text. `cmake-gui` does not show internal entries. They may be used to store variables persistently across runs. |

If I want to store a CMake-style<sup>*</sup> list of file paths or directory paths, should I define it as FILEPATH or PATH, respectively? As a STRING?

<sub>* - i.e. represented in a semicolon-separated string.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FILEPATH` and `PATH` are suitable only for a **single** path. E.g. when a user fills parameters of one of these types, CMake GUI provides a path-selection dialog.

For the list of paths use `STRING` parameter.

---

In case you will use non-semicolon separator between paths, you will need to convert that separator to semicolon before use that list in `CMakeLists.txt`. E.g. you could choose a colon (`:`) to be used a separator, like for the PATH variable on Linux.

Comment: Clarified my question to say that I mean a CMake-style list.